# Hibernate clone entity without lazy fields

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private int age;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private Person person;
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persons")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "number")
    private String number;
```

The person is LAZY. I load one user and detach it.

```
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        User user = userService.getOne(1L);

        userService.detach(user);

        System.out.println(user.getName());
        System.out.println(user.getAge());
        Person person = user.getPerson();
        System.out.println(person.getName());
        System.out.println(person.getNumber());
    }
```

But when I call `user.getPerson()` - it does not throw exceptions. I expect exception because I detach entity and try to call LAZY field but it still works.

I want to create a clone of the user, without person and save as a new entity.

```
User user = userService.getOne(1L);
userService.detach(user);
user.setId(null)//autogenerate id
```

but when I save user, person clone too. I can set null:

```
User user = userService.getOne(1L);
userService.detach(user);
user.setId(null);
user.setPerson(null);
```

But person lazy and it looks like a hack. And what's the point then `detach` method...

EDIT:

Very interesting thing - If I start example application in debugging with breakpoints - all work fine, but if I deselect all breakpoints I get exception in the console:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [com.example.detachexample.User#1] - no Session
```

Comment: When you call detach, the object is detached from session (like transaction) and won't be saved to database unless you attach it at some point again... But all of it's properties remains the same

Comment: It seems in your use case, you need to flush the session after detaching the 'user'. You'll need an open session once you're ready to 'clone' the object

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it, you are calling detach on a clone? Well that clone is not of a plain User object, but of the proxy that extends the User object.

You need to get the raw loaded entity first using `unproxy`.

```
User olduser = userService.getOne(1L);
User user = org.hibernate.Hibernate.unproxy(olduser);
if (olduser == user) userService.detach(user);
user.setId(null)//autogenerate id
user.getPerson().setId(null); // so you will generate this as well
user.getPerson().setUser(user); // so that it will point to the correct new entity
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that at the point of `detach` the `Person` has been loaded actually.

This is possible according to `FetchType` documentation:

> The LAZY strategy is a hint to the persistence provider runtime that
>   data should be fetched lazily when it is first accessed. The
>   implementation is permitted to eagerly fetch data for which the LAZY
>   strategy hint has been specified.

So take a look at the Hibernate debug logs and most likely there will be a join to the Person somewhere along with the select of its fields.

Comment: Yes, I saw hibernate logs. first - load the only user without the person. After that, I call the detach method.  And after that, I call `user.getPerson()`. And hibernate makes a new query(standard lazy loading). But I don't understand How can it do it if the user already detached.